# pick three random number from ten and made x**2+x*y-y**2+z smallest

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I get `L=[1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`
then `func(L)` should return `-4`, because  `min(x^2+x*y-y^2+z)=-4`, for any `x`, `y`, `z` in `L`.

any better way to build `func` without three `for` loop?

Comment: Assign the smallest number to x, the 2nd smallest number to z, and the biggest number to y? (Assuming they're all non-negative)

Comment: are those integers? positive integers? or floats?

Comment: Can you put some parenthesis in your min() example?

Comment: @Bijan yep, there are integers which in [-512,512]

Comment: @ninesalt it doesn't require paranthesis. it has four obvious terms

Answer (score 0):

We will calculate all unqiue permutations of `L` to get of rid of duplicate computations. Then perform your function on all permutations, finding the min.

Retrieve a unique set from `L` and put all permutations into a list:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

L = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
np_array = np.unique(L)
```

Adjusting for when the number of unique values is not at least three:

```
int_len = 3 - len(np_array)
if int_len > 0:
    np_array = np.pad(np_array, (int_len,0), 'edge')

li = np_array.tolist()
```

Finding all combinations with length `3`:

```
perms = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(li, 3))
```

Re-assign the three array columns to their corresponding variable:

```
a = np.array(perms)
x = a[:,0]
y = a[:,1]
z = a[:,2]
```

Calculate the function for every permutation in array and perform min over result:

```
minimum_value = np.min(np.square(x) + np.multiply(x,y) - np.square(y) + z)
```

Comment: OP was asking for an alternative over using three loops so it looks like he is looking for something that performs better. Using permutations doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: @ninesalt this is the fastest way I can think of getting to the answer. You need all unique permutations to ensure you search the entire function domain for the available set.

Comment: @Aran-Fey generalized code to work for any input array.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure if this really does what the OP wants, because it doesn't respect the number of occurrences in the input (i.e. with an input of `[1, 2, 3]`, it could choose to set all three variables to `1` or `2` or `3`), but that's up to the OP to clarify.

Comment: @Aran-Fey the answer provided allows for all three variables to be set to say `(1,1,1)`.